# Select query to count results based on another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, one with a list of members and the other with a list of surveys those members have completed.

I need to count how many surveys members have completed, based on how long they have been members. For example, I would like to pull all members that have signed up within 2 months and then count how many surveys those members have completed.

Each member has a unique member_id, which is stored in the member table and also in the table with the completed surveys - so I can search through the surveys table for the member_id to count the number of completed.

Also, the member table has a sign-up date stored, which can be used to pick only the past two months of new members.

I hope this makes sense. I'm not sure how to post the table structure (from PhpMyAdmin).

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to list **all** members even if they didn't completed any of the surveys since their date of registration you have to use an **outer join** (`LEFT JOIN` in the example below):

```
SELECT m.member_id, COUNT(s.member_id) completed
  FROM members m LEFT JOIN surveys s 
    ON m.member_id = s.member_id
 WHERE m.signup_date >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH -- or LAST_DAY(CURDATE()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 2 MONTH depending on what exactly you mean by "within 2 months"
 GROUP BY m.member_id;
```

Sample output:

```
| MEMBER_ID | COMPLETED |
|-----------|-----------|
|         2 |         1 |
|         3 |         0 | 
|         4 |         2 |
```

**UPDATE:** The easiest way to get the total in the same query is by applying [`WITH ROLLUP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-modifiers.html) modifier to `GROUP BY` clause.

```
SELECT m.member_id, COUNT(s.member_id) completed
  FROM members m LEFT JOIN surveys s 
    ON m.member_id = s.member_id
 WHERE m.signup_date >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH
 GROUP BY m.member_id WITH ROLLUP
```

Sample output:

```
| MEMBER_ID | COMPLETED |
|-----------|-----------|
|         2 |         1 |
|         3 |         0 |
|         4 |         2 |
|    (null) |         3 |
```

The last row with `NULL` in `member_id` column will contain the total.

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5fa9c/13)** demo for both queries.

Comment: Thank you. That is excactly what I am looking for. I know this is a total newbie question, but can I expand the query, so that it returns the total number of completed surveys?
That way I can divide the total completed surveys by the total number of members (including those who didn't complete anything) to get the average activity

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT member_id, COUNT(*) AS completed_surveys
FROM member_table m
JOIN survey_completion_table s ON m.member_id = s.member_id
WHERE m.signup_date >= NOW() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH
GROUP BY m.member_id;
```